# Netbeans auto complete doesn't work on class assignment

Tags: php, ide, netbeans-7

I have this class saved in foo.php

[image]

And then this class saved in bar.php

[image]

As you can see, auto-complete suggestions doesn't work.
Note that if I place `Bar` class inside foo.php, it does work.

Auto-complete should work even on separate files as long as their in one project right?

BTW I am using Netbeans IDE 7.2

Comment: Sorry I can t delete my comment right now..will do as soon as I get to my laptop. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

A comment must be placed above the variable declaration

```
/**
 *
 * @var LP_pdo
 */
 protected $hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans doesn't know that `$hello` has been instantiated as a `new LP_pdo()` and therefore cannot do code completion for you.